# jquery scrollto fade out then display:none

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm trying to `fadeOut` a DIV that contains an image and then have the DIV switch to `display:none` so links under the DIV are clickable.

I'm doing this as I want the image to stick to the bottom left of the page.

I have:

```
<script>
jQuery(function( $ ){


    function fade_home_top() {
        if ( $(window).width() > 800 ) {
        window_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            $(".mom-son").css({
                  'opacity' : 1-(window_scroll/300)
            });
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() { fade_home_top(); });

});
</script>
```

The ideal would be the DIV (therefore image) `fadeOut` on scroll and then `display:none`

I'm using ScrollTo.js.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWLR8/1/)

Comment: fiddle pls!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: as you want to fadein or fadeout on scroll

Comment: new to this so will attempt a fiddle.

Comment: ok so do u fadein on scroll or fadeout

Comment: as the page moves down it fades out. as it moves up it fades back in.

Comment: in your function you could just check if 1 - (window_scroll / 300) <= 0 and if it is set display:none, else display:block

Comment: Thanks Kai. Being new to jquery how would one write that in the above code?

Comment: have a look at jQuery's animate function, it allows you to animate the opacity and other CSS-styles (thus fadeIn/fadeOut). Fortunately, jQuery has this buildin (`fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`) Then chain `hide()` to it.  (thus something like `$(".mom-son").fadeOut().hide();`

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    function fade_home_top() {
        if ( $(window).width() > 800 ) {
            var window_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            $(".mom-son").css({opacity:1-window_scroll/300});
            if(1-window_scroll/300 <= 0){
                $(".mom-son").css({display:'none'});
            }
            else
            {
                $(".mom-son").css({display:'block'});
            }
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(fade_home_top);
});
```

Basically, add a check to see if the opacity is less than or equal to zero. if it is, set display to none. else, display block. window_scroll should be declared. Also, pass a reference to the function. no need to call an anonymous function that just calls the other function.

http://jsfiddle.net/PWLR8/5/

Comment: Hi Kai I checked your fiddle. It is not coming back over here as well. What can be the reason?

Comment: It does for me. I'm on chrome on mac. What browser are you on?

Comment: I'll have to check from home later

Comment: ha... $(window).width() is resolving to the width of the fiddle viewport. My work monitor is huge so it probably met the 800px requirement. If you try this code on a normal site it should work so long as the window is greater than 800px wide. For the fiddle, change that to like 400 and see if it works for you then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery fadeOut function. Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWLR8/3/) and let me know.

Code Snippet:

```
function fade_home_top() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 800 ) {
    window_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(1-window_scroll/300){
             $(".mom-son").fadeOut();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to check out increase the output window width as we have set window width> 800 check

Updated Answer (As per Kai's suggestion)

I have now added fadeIn() for the else part to get the element back on.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWLR8/7/)

Updated Code:

```
function fade_home_top() {
        if ( $(window).width() > 800 ) {
        window_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (window_scroll >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) || window_scroll ==0){
                $(".mom-son").fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                 $(".mom-son").fadeOut();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i wouldnt use fadeout. Also, you'll want an else in there or it will never come back. see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PWLR8/5/

Comment: @user3634131: Whose fiddle Kai or mine or both?

Comment: @V31 - yours faded out, but not back in. it needs an else statement and fadeOut is an animated method, so it might conflict with opacity settings on a scroll listener.

Comment: I think he is handling the opacity setting in order to have the fadeOut effect

Comment: true, but you're calling fadeOut on an element whose opacity is already 0, and while this may technically work, it might be better to call show() or hide() which are instantaneous and equal to display block/none. cause if you are scrolling from 0, you are animating the opacity of an element at the same time as setting its opacity on the scroll event. I'm not sure there are side effects. It might be perfectly fine. But it also may not be the most process friendly decision. Still an option though.